# How to get the new selected date from asp:calendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, calendar, autopostback

So I have made an asp:calendar and I want to access the new selected date on the following page load after a post-back.

The code i am using is:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calEndDate" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>

Request.Form[calEndDate.UniqueID]
```

And it always returns null. I am able to retrieve the selected date, but that will give me the previously selected date, not the new one.

The message i get when hovering over the 'calEndDate' is:

`calEndDate = {SelectedDate = The name 'SelectedData' does not exist in the current context}`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So from what i was able to find there is a problem with asp:calendar controls. Something prevents you grabbing the detaihttp://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/254459/the-name-selecteddata-does-not-exist-in-the-current-contextls on postback.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than on Page_Load, use the [**`OnSelectionChanged`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of Calendar control to get your selected date as:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calEndDate" runat="server" 
     OnSelectionChanged="SelectedDate_Change">
</asp:Calendar>
```

and your Selection changed event looks like:

```
void SelectedDate_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         Label1.Text = calEndDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
      }
```

Also the Calendar control you are using is an asp.net server control, so access it directly using its ID as in above code snippet rather than using Request.Form